# The public key encrypted value can get decrypted with someone else’s private key

Tags: rsa, encryption-asymmetric

Today I was just testing my code and found that:

Say Bob and Alice have keypairs (pub1,priv1) and (pub2,priv2) respectively.

If Bob encrypts messages with **pub2** (Alice’s public key) and then he again encrypts that cypher-text with **priv1** (bob’s private key), it returned same bytes as messages! I.e. bob was able to decrypt cypher text encrypted with **pub2**

But it turns out that when message was encrypted by **pub2** and **priv1**, they strangely generated same cypher text, also **priv1** and **priv2** both can decrypt them regardless…

Here's the calculations I performed:

```
e = 65537

//Bob's stuff
p = 512 bit prime number
q = 512 bit prime number
n = p * q (where * means multiply)
on = (p-1) * (q-1)
d = modulo inverse of (e, on)

//Alice's stuff
p1 = 512 bit prime number
q1 = 512 bit prime number
n1 = p1 * q1
on1 = (p1-1) * (q1-1)
d1 = modulo inverse of (e, on1)
```

so when say I want to encrypt `a = 97 (according to utf8)` (let's forget about vulnerabilities of using small number for encryption)

so I tried encrypting like: `c1 = mod(97 * e, n1)` i.e. encrypted with Alice's public key.

Now I want Alice to verify that the message belongs to Bob only (let's not talk about x509 as of now)

so I encrypted that cyphertext `c1` with Bob's private key **priv1 (or d)**  like:

```
c2 = mod(c1 * d, on)
```

So that Alice can decrypt it twice and make sure that it belongs to Bob only as:

```
c3 = mod(c2 * e, n) //as we encrypted c1 with bob's pvt key, now it should be decrypted using his public key.
```

and to decrypt the message:

```
c4 = mod(c3 * d1, on1) //should give original message i.e. 97
```

BUT, it however does not happen the way it should, rather `mod(97 * e, n)`, `mod(97 * e, n1)`, `mod(97 * e, on)`, `mod(97 * e, on1)` gives same output.. How's that possible? (n, on) and (n1, on1) are quite different. Also I was able to decrypt message encrypted with above method with anyone's private key whose corresponding public key was NOT used for encryption at all.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Im showing what calculations I did, both in code and the terminal, and the output of it in the comments

Comment: 97 * 65537 = 6357089. The numbers are so small that the mod operation doesn't do anything. **THIS IS NOT THE RSA ALGORITHM**

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk ok so is the question confusing? For me I think it's clear what I mean, but let me edit it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249834/discussion-between-sandip-and-president-james-k-polk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RSA cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) uses [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) as a primitive operation rather than modular multiplication as you appear to be employing. If n = p * q is the RSA modulus, the product of primes p and q, and e and d are the encrypt and decrypt exponents respectively, then encryption is c = x<sup>e</sup> mod n and decryption is x = c<sup>d</sup> mod n, where x is the plaintext integer. Of course modular multiplication is a key component of modular exponentiation. In python you can use the three-argument form of the [built-in pow](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#pow) function to easily and efficiently perform modular exponentiation, so simply

```py
c = pow(x, e, n)
x = pow(c, d, n)
```

Using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) to [explore RSA (includes RSA tutorial)](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/numtheory_rsa.html?highlight=ring%20integers%20modulo%20n) is also relatively easy. In sage you can indicate that the arithmetic is to be done in the *ring* of integers modulo n by something like

```py
R = Integers(n)
x = R(97)
c = x ^ e
decrypted = c ^ d
print(decrypted == x)  # prints True
```

Notice that in sage `^` is the exponentiation operator, whereas in python it is the exclusive or (xor) operator.

If the ring of integers modulo n is a little too exotic for you then you can just use regular integer arithmetic in sage with the [`mod()`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/finite_rings/sage/rings/finite_rings/integer_mod.html#sage.rings.finite_rings.integer_mod.mod) and [`power_mod()`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/arith/misc.html#sage.arith.misc.power_mod) functions.